# Mixpanel in-app messages using Ruby client

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, mixpanel

I am using `mixpanel-ruby` gem to track Rails application's user interaction. I want to use the in-app messaging feature of mixpanel to send customized notifications to users. Do I still have to include mixpanel JS client for this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, you will need to use the JS client. Since the Ruby gem is only on the server side there isn't anything on the client side to connect the user to Mixpanel to use the messaging feature.

From their [requirements](https://mixpanel.com/help/reference/web-inapp-messages):

1. Include the latest version of the Mixpanel JavaScript library on
   your website.
2. Make sure you are identifying your users in your
   website's JavaScript code.
3. Create a web in-app message on the Messages tab of the Mixpanel website.